# How to use GnuPG (Libgcrypt) generated keys with RSACryptoServiceProvider?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, gnupg

Is it possible to use PGP keys in .NET's RSA?

I tried this code, without success.

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2();
certificate.Import("C:\\All Public Keys.asc");
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey;
```

How to load this key?

Comment: The keys created by GPG do not seem to be X.509 certificates, so the `X509Certificate2` object is not intended to load them. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509, which contrasts GPG with X.509, and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148438.aspx.

Comment: Have you looked at bouncy castle functionality?